# Input addEventListener - click works, onchange/oninput doesn't

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to dynamically create a form, and add event listeners to the inputs.

The click event listener works as expected, while the onchange/oninput one does not.

What is the problem?

```js
function createInput(location, options) {
    let input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = "input"
    input.name = options.name;

    input.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        console.log(e) // This one works
    });

    input.addEventListener('onchange', (e) => {
        console.log(e) // This one doesn't!
    });

    document.getElementById(location).appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `'change'` instead of `'onchange'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event name is `change`, not `onchange`. With `addEventListener`, you never use the "on" prefix.

Side note: `input.type = "input"` is incorrect. There is no `input` [type](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-type). The `input` will be a text input, just like `type = "text"`.

Comment: Damn, how could I miss that. Code fatigue is real! Thanks, works great now.